# Consuming WCF service in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, ado.net

I am consuming a WCF service in a Windows Forms application. My WCF service has two classes called `FulltimeEmployee` and `ParttimeEmployee`. I want to register users based on employee type. The user type will come from emu. When I click the submit button, I always get a message:

> Please select the employee type

as shown in the screen shot.

Here is the code form class..

```
 [KnownType(typeof(FullTimeEmployee))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PartTimeEmployee))]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://pragimtech.com/Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private string _gender;
        private DateTime _dateOfBirth;

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set { _gender = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return _dateOfBirth; }
            set { _dateOfBirth = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public EmployeeType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EmployeeType
    {
        FullTimeEmployee = 1,
        PartTimeEmployee = 2
    }
}
```

Here is WCF service code to register employee based on type:

```
public void SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSaveEmployee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parameterId = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Id",
                    Value = employee.Id
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterId);

        SqlParameter parameterName = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Name",
                    Value = employee.Name
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);

        SqlParameter parameterGender = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Gender",
                    Value = employee.Gender
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterGender);

        SqlParameter parameterDateOfBirth = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@DateOfBirth",
                    Value = employee.DateOfBirth
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDateOfBirth);

        SqlParameter parameterEmployeeType = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@EmployeeType",
                    Value = employee.Type
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmployeeType);

        if (employee.GetType() == typeof(FullTimeEmployee))
        {
            SqlParameter parameterAnnualSalary = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@AnnualSalary",
                        Value = ((FullTimeEmployee)employee).AnnualSalary
                    };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAnnualSalary);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlParameter parameterHourlyPay = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@HourlyPay",
                        Value = ((PartTimeEmployee)employee).HourlyPay,
                    };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterHourlyPay);

            SqlParameter parameterHoursWorked = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@HoursWorked",
                        Value = ((PartTimeEmployee)employee).HoursWorked
                    };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterHoursWorked);
        }

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Here is the Windows Form application code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyService.HalifaxServiceClient myservice = new MyService.HalifaxServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxService");

    MyService.Employee employee = null;

    if (((MyService.EmployeeType)Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue)) == MyService.EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
    {
        employee = new MyService.FullTimeEmployee
                   {
                      Id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                      Name = txtName.Text,
                      Gender = comboBox1.Text,
                      DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateOfBirth.Text),
                      Type = MyService.EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee,
                      AnnualSalary = Convert.ToInt32(txtAnnualSalary.Text),
                   };
        myservice.SaveEmployee(employee);
        label8.Text = "Employee saved";
    }
    else if (((MyService.EmployeeType)Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue)) == MyService.EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee)
    {
        employee = new MyService.PartTimeEmployee
                       {
                           Id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                           Name = txtName.Text,
                           Gender = comboBox1.Text,
                           DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateOfBirth.Text),
                           Type = MyService.EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee,
                           HourlyPay = Convert.ToInt32(txtHourlyPay.Text),
                           HoursWorked = Convert.ToInt32(txtHoursWorked.Text),
                       };
        myservice.SaveEmployee(employee);
        label8.Text = "Employee saved";
    }
    else
    {
       label8.Text = "Please select Employee Type";
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox2.Text == "FullTimeEmployee")
    {
        txtHourlyPay.Visible = false;
        txtHoursWorked.Visible = false;
        label6.Visible = false;
        label7.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "PartTimeEmployee")
    {
        txtHourlyPay.Visible = true;
        txtHoursWorked.Visible = true;
        label6.Visible = true;
        label7.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

When I click the submit button its shows

> Please select the employee type

and does not insert a new employee into SQL Server database..

Here is screenshot of output:

[image: Click here to see the out put]

Comment: Ok i doing it now.  Pleas wait

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: How is `comboBox2` populated?

Comment: Seems to me like a problem on the client side. Did you try to run it in debug mode and check what's the value of `comboBox2.SelectedValue`?

Comment: Yes you are right problem with client side . I tried to mention employee type from combobox2 but shows error

Comment: when I build solution I got this errors  ... Non-invocable member 'EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee' cannot be used like a method. \ADDEMPLOYEE.cs// on this line  Type = MyService.EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee(comboBox2.SelectedValue),